# Node.js - expressjs - multer req.files outputs empty

Tags: node.js, express, multer

i'm using multer to get a file from this form

```
<form action="/api/pimage" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="file" name="profileimage">
        <input type="submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

using this serverside script

```
app.post('/api/pimage', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body, req.files);
});
```

the problem is that req.body is printing out { profileimage: 'image.png' }
and req.files is printing out {}
where you see the problem?
thanks

P.S. i'm using `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));` to get req.body and `app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/'}));` for req.files

Comment: Does the directory `uploads` exist and is it writable?

Comment: The directory is auto created by multer on start

Comment: If you're seeing `req.body.profileimage` then your request is not being sent as `multipart/form-data` somehow. That's what you would see when the `Content-Type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Can you put `console.dir(req.headers['content-type'])` in your `app.post()` handler?

Comment: Yea you are right is printing out 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
not multipart/form-data

Answer (score 2):

I found that using `multer` alongside `bodyParser` can cause `req.file` to be undefined. Make sure to check that also if you're having issues.

Answer (score 1):

I put MY (there are many I imagine and surely better) solution to help many people like me because I have searched during 1 entire day ;-(

---

```
var express = require('express');
var fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
var fs = require("fs");
var app = express();

console.log('étape 0');

app.use(express.static('mesStatic'));
app.use(fileUpload());

console.log('étape 1');

app.get('/indexFileUpload.htm', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "indexFileUpload.htm" );
})

console.log('étape 2');

app.post('/file_upload', function (req, res) {

   console.log('étape 3');
   console.log('req.files:' , req.files);

   if (!req.files) {
       res.send('No files to upload.');
       return;
   }

   console.log('req.files.file.data:' , req.files.file.data);
   var bufDataFile = new Buffer(req.files.file.data, "utf-8");
   console.log('étape 3.1');
   console.log('__dirname : ' + __dirname);

   fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/file_upload/output.txt', bufDataFile,  function(err) {
      if (err) {
         return console.error(err);
      }
      else {
         console.log("Data written successfully !");
      }      
      console.log('étape 4');
      res.end('Fin OK !!!');  
   })
})
var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port

   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide your upload function defined for multer before asking for `req.file` in `function(req, res)`, you can follow the code given below

```
    var Storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, callback) {
            callback(null, "./images/");
        },
        filename: function (req, file, callback) {
            callback(null, file.fieldname + '_' + Date.now() + '.jpg');
        }
    });
    var upload = multer({ storage: Storage }).single('imagePath');

    router.post('/file_upload', upload, function(req, res, next){
        console.log(req.file);
var Storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, "./public/images/");
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.fieldname + '_' + Date.now() + '.jpg');
    }
});
var upload = multer({ storage: Storage }).single('imagePath');

router.post('/add-product', upload, function(req, res, next){
    var newProduct = new Product();
}
```